# Clearing Data from a Data Extension through API call from .Net

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I am trying to clear a data extension via API call. I have ExactTarget web service reference into my project as https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl

I have found a sample code to clear a data extension via API call at here on ET website:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/clearing_data_from_a_data_extension/

I have tried using the sample code provided on ET website, but I am getting an error resolving this reference:

**ExactTarget.Integration.IPartnerFrameworkInterface proxy = null;**

Can someone please explain how to resolve this reference? My full code can be seen in this image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are missing some using statements
using ProfileCenter.ExactTarge.??  ?

Answer (score 0):

That example wraps some of the objects a bit which makes things a bit confusing.  Simplified specifically for WCF, it would look like:

```
public void ClearDE()
{
    SoapClient api = new SoapClient();
    api.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "ccc";
    api.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "ccc";

    string requestID;
    string status;
    string statusmessage;

    DataExtension DE = new DataExtension();
    DE.ObjectID = "a23790c3-88c0-4f08-a253-1024d9e74a2c";

    PerformResult[] presult = api.Perform(new PerformOptions(), "ClearData", new APIObject[] { DE }, out status, out statusmessage, out requestID);

    foreach (PerformResult result in presult)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusMessage);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(requestID + ": " + status);
}
```

Keep in mind, this function only works for Enterprise 2.0 accounts so please verify that is the account type being used.